DateTicksFormat -> Automatic different in 14.1 than in 14.0
In v Mathematica 14.0, the default automatic setting for DateTicksFormat in DateListPlot displayed the time on the horizontal axis with a nice hh:mm:ss format. In Wolfram 14.1, the automatic setting displays the time with an am/pm format (and the dates with slashes). Of course I can specify the exact format with the DateTicksFormat option, but this would have to be done for each case specifically. The automatic default was very convenient.
Is there some setting to revert back to the 14.0 version?
Example from documentation for DateTicksFormat:
DateListPlot[{13, 14, 17, 24, 26, 28, 29, 31, 42, 44}, {"1:00 PM", 
 Automatic, "Hour"}]



A hackery workaround would be to change the internal list of formats, which is used when deciding how to display the tick labels, to the old one:
System`DateListPlotDump`automaticTickFun[i_] := {
   "Year", 
   "MonthNameShort", 
   {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day"}, 
   {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}, 
   {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}, 
   {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}, 
   {"Second", ".", "Millisecond"}}[[i]]


Obviously, this is fiddling with internal workings, so it might not work in later versions.
Note that the new list in version 14.1 is:
System`DateListPlotDump`automaticTickFun[i_] := {
   "Year", 
   {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}, 
   {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Day"}, 
   {"MonthShort", "/", "DayShort", " ", "Hour12Short", "\[ThinSpace]", "AMPMLowerCase"}, 
   {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}, 
   {"Hour", ":", "Minute", ":", "Second"}, 
   {"Second", ".", "Millisecond"}}[[i]]


This is exactly the problem - thanks for figuring this out! How can one change this internal function?

@hippo3773, just execute the first piece of code in my answer. You can also add it to init.m file so that you don't have to do this manually every time.

Works!   Many thanks!
